# Missing values in Random Forest Prediction: Is there an R package that is similar to Breiman?

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction, missing-data

Is there an implementation of random forest prediction in R that replicates Leo Breiman's implementation regarding missing values? In Breiman's Fortran code [[described here]](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#missing1),

> If labels no not exist, then each case in the test set is replicated nclass times (nclass= number of classes). The first replicate of a case is assumed to be class 1 and the class one fills used to replace missing values. The 2nd replicate is assumed class 2 and the class 2 fills used on it. 
>   This augmented test set is run down the tree. In each set of replicates, the one receiving the most votes determines the class of the original case.

In the RandomForest package [[page 16 (predict](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf))], that is supposed to be based on Breiman's Fortran code, it says:

> If the object inherits from randomForest.formula, then any data with NA are silently omitted from the prediction.

Which means in the randomForest package, the predictions are just returned as NA. Did I misunderstand? Is there any R package that predicts values similar to Breiman's code?